# Elastic search filename search not working with dots in filename

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I have elasticsearch mapping as follows:

```
{
  "info": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {"type":"date","format":"epoch_second"},
      "user": {"type":"keyword" },
      "filename": {"type":"text"}
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to do match query on filename, it works properly when I don't give dot in search input, but when dot in included, it returns many false results.

I learnt that standard analyzer is the issue. It breaks search input on dots and then search. What analyzer I can use in this case? The filenames can be millions and I don't want something with takes lot of memory and time. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about filenames here, i would suggest using the [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) analyzer. This will not split the string and just index it as it is. 
You could also just change ur mapping from text to keyword instead.